# FosUserBundle don't send email to resset password

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a simple form to login and reminder password, I overwrite the FOSUser template and everything works fine, but when I want to email the password reminder I do not get it to the mail.

This looks like a swiftmailer and fos configuration in `config.yml`:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }         
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AirblogBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "admin@admin.com"
        sender_name: "Admin"
    resetting:
        email:
            from_email: 
                address:        noreply@yoursite.com
                sender_name:    No Reply
        token_ttl: 0
```

After sending the email from the **resetting/request** path, I get the following information:

*An email has been sent to ...@wp.pl. It contains a link you must click to reset your password.*

Which seems correct because the address entered in the form has the same ending, but my mailbox does not receive any message.

ps: One more question, how to simply overwrite the Twig template, so the login and reminder of the hymn was on one page? Do you need to overwrite the controller?

Comment: for overriding templates, you can use same names in your `app/Resources`

Answer (score 3):

**Did you configure the needed parameters of  SwiftMailerBundle well ?**

First of all I suggest you to use Symfony's command to check your swift mailer configuration.

Specify the good arguments to send you a debug mail with reading the help command

```
php app/console swiftmailer:email:send --help
```

You should receive a mail on the email address you wrote in command.
After this step you can assume that your mail configuration is good

**Reset your forget password request**

One important (in the version installed on my project, composer requirement **~2.0**) thing to know that is FOSUserBundle don't **resend** mail if you didn't click on the previous reset link sended BUT he display to you the message that he sended the mail.

If you want to "reset" your password request for a specific user

```
UPDATE user SET confirmation_token = NULL, password_requested_at = NULL WHERE username = "yourdebugusername"
```

**Extending FOSUserBundle Twig templates**

You should read [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html)

Basically you can override all the FOSUserTemplate under `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views`

I hope it's help !

Comment: I try:  php app/console swiftmailer:email:send , but receives an error - [OK] 1 emails were successfully sent.

[2017-08-25 08:24:55] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with
 host 127.0.0.1 [ #10061]

Comment: Verify your `mailer_*` parameters configuration

Comment: Configure mail_ in the parameters.yaml file: `    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: stefan16111@wp.pl
    mailer_password:mypass` . I changed : swiftmailer:
    transport: mail , I do not receive errors in the console and I get a message about sending the email correctly, but no message appears in the mailbox

Answer (score 0):

For overriding FOSUser twig template looks the [Symfony Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html)